# CSS adjustment on float left

Tags: css

On [my site](https://investorbhai.com/test/) header, I can see the logo in the center of the black bar while it is set to show at the left with float CSS.

Also, the menu which need to be placed at the right f the same black bar is showing way down making the pink area below that of more height.

I have used float left to make the logo to left on the black area but it is not working for me.

Anything I am missing?

Thank you in advance.